# Determining whether an element is contained in the radical of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Consider the ideal $J =\langle120,x^3-x^2\rangle$ in the ring $\mathbb Z[x]$. How can we decide whether the element $x^3-x+15$ is contained in the radical of $J$ ?

Comment: If the ring consisted of polynomials with coefficients in a field, the answer is clearly yes, but we are unable to use Nullstellensatz in this case.

Comment: I think if I do a Groebner style elimination basis of $\langle 120, x^3 - x^2, x^3 - x + 15 - t \rangle$, I get the relations involving only $t$ are $\langle 120, t^2 - 30t + 225 \rangle$ - and then modding that out by 2, you would see that $t$ cannot be nilpotent in the quotient.

Comment: The radical of an ideal is the intersection of its minimal primes. One of these is the ideal $P=(2,x)$. Does your polynomial belong to P?

Answer (score 1):

Every polynomial $p \in J$ satisfies $2 \mid p(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$; and therefore, this would also be satisfied for any $p \in \sqrt{J}$.  However, $x^3 - x + 15$ does not satisfy this relation.

Comment: Oh, also - we see $x^3 - x \in \sqrt{J}$, so if $x^3 - x + 15$ were in $\sqrt{J}$, then 15 would also have to be in $\sqrt{J}$, which it isn't.